# NodeJS Redis client compatible with NodeJS version 4.8.x?

Tags: node.js, redis

Does anyone know of a NodeJS Redis client compatible with NodeJS version 4.8.xish?

I have tried node-redis and ioredis both and have ran into issues.

Answer (score 0):

The **Node.js** **Redis** client is generally compatible with **Node.js** version 4.8.x, but the specific version of the client you are using may have different requirements.

It's worth noting that **Node.js** 4.8.x is an old version, it reached its end-of-life on April 30th, 2018, and it's recommended to use a more recent version of **Node.js** for your application.

It is also important to check if the **Redis** server version you are using is compatible with the **Redis** client library you are using.

If you are using an old version of the **Redis** client library, you may encounter issues with compatibility. In this case, it's recommended to upgrade to a more recent version of the library.